# OLEObjects OptionButtons event handling

Tags: excel, vba

I have a group of OLEObjects OptionButtons but i've realized than i can't handle on change event when one Optionbutton is activated to trigger a Sub or Function like Form Objects. I need to use OLEObjets in the project, OLEObject are in a sheet. I need to get which OptionButton has activated and trigger an action

Please what would be the way to go?

[image]

Comment: **Why** do you need to use ActiveX ones?

Comment: Link them with a cell and trigger the cell value change with the worksheet_change event?

Comment: @Rory seems silly but i need to resize the controls

Comment: Yes, it does. :) Not worth it, in my opinion, for all the drawbacks of activex. You can use the event for each control to call a common routine and pass an argument indicating the control that was clicked, or use a class.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ, please  could you provide a quick example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a classmodule, name it OptionClass, put code below in Class:

```
Public WithEvents Opt As MSForms.OptionButton

Private Sub Opt_Click()
'change will trigger multiple optionbuttons
    MsgBox Opt.Name
End Sub
```

In a module:

```
Dim OptionButtons() As New OptionClass 'better to do this in 2 seperate lines

Sub PutOn(Sht As Object)
    Dim Ctl As OLEObject, i As Long

    For Each Ctl In Sht.OLEObjects
    
         If TypeName(Ctl.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
               i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve OptionButtons(1 To i)
                Set OptionButtons(i).Opt = Ctl.Object
         End If
    Next Ctl

End Sub
Sub start()
  PutOn Sheet2
End Sub
```

Adjust to your needs